# How to update pip when traditional way does not work?

Tags: python, pip

I get the following error:

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.1; however, version 20.3 is available.

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5]
```

Was using `pip install --upgrade pip` and `c:\python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Neither of these approaches did work. I am a bit of newbie when it comes to Python and not sure what to do now.

Why I need to update pip you ask? I want to update pip in order to download various libraries in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` if you normally just call `python` from the command line.

You could also try running the command as Administrator.

It would also help answer your question if you edited your post to include the actual error messages.

Comment: Apparently, I should: "Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions."